# Using an associative array as data for D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, associative-array

I have a very simple D3 example that first reads data into an associative array, then displays it in a bar graph.

I can't seem to get anything to display using this method though. Instead, I have to insert a task in between: Read the data into an associative array, copy that data into a simple array, then display the bar graph using the simple array.

```
chart.selectAll("div")
     .data(genreAssociative)
     .enter().append("div")
     .style("width", function(d) { return d * 10 + "px"; })
     .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

The above does not work.

```
genreSimple = [];
for (var genre in genreAssociative) genreSimple.push(genreAssociative[genre]);         
chart.selectAll("div")
     .data(genreSimple)
     .enter().append("div")
     .style("width", function(d) { return d * 10 + "px"; })
     .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

The above does; using a simple array as an intermediary. Is there a special way to iterate over an associative array instead of a standard array?

Comment: it appears from the included information that the chart.data function does not accept a javascript object (aka "associative array"). If this is the case, then you have no choice but to convert to an Array.

Comment: They are not called associative arrays in JavaScript. I tend to get hung up on this terminology because usually the people who day associative array will declare it as an array, like PHP.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the functions [d3.values](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_values) or [d3.entries](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_entries) to work directly with associative arrays. You simply need to take it into account in the functions that set attributes (e.g. `function(d) { return d.value; }`).

Comment: This solution didn't completely work but it pointed me in the right direction. By replacing ".data(genreAssociative)" with ".data(d3.values(genreAssociative))" I was able to get data displaying correctly, though unfortunately this loses key information (so I can't display the key as text, for example).

Comment: Did you try using `.data(d3.entries(genreAssociative))`?

Comment: Yes, but then I have access to the keys and not the values. In my bar graph I want the values for the bar length, and the keys for the labels.

Comment: `d3.entries()` returns an array where each element has a `key` and a `value` member. You should be able to get both keys and values that way.

Comment: That's it! Thanks very much! That'll teach me to read the documentation closer next time.

Answer (score 2):

I found that in order for bar chart generation to work well, the following format works best.  It's based on the the D3 post-parsed CSV format.

```
var dataSet1 = [
  {xCoordinate: "Legend String 1", magnitude: 54, link: "http://www.if4it.com"},
  {xCoordinate: "Legend String 2", magnitude: 21, link: "http://www.if4it.com/glossary.html"},
  {xCoordinate: "Legend String 3", magnitude: 31, link: "http://www.if4it.com/resources.html"},
  {xCoordinate: "Legend String 4", magnitude: 14, link: "http://www.if4it.com/taxonomy.html"},
  {xCoordinate: "Legend String 5", magnitude: 19, link: "http://www.if4it.com/disciplines.html"},
  {xCoordinate: "Legend String 6", magnitude: 47, link: "http://www.if4it.com"},
  {xCoordinate: "Legend String 7", magnitude: 27, link: "http://www.if4it.com/glossary.html"}];
```

The format allows for the correlation of coordinates, magnitudes, legends and html links to each other.

A working example can be found at: http://bl.ocks.org/2164562.