# When loading .json in d3.js i'm not getting an array of Objects

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to load .json into d3 but i'm not getting an array of objects.

My json structure is like this:

```
{
  "01": {
    "a": "7.9146197142424404",
    "b": "8", 
    "c": "64.52183289033583", 
    "d": "bar"
  }, 
  "02": {
    "a": "6.1448162722275468", 
    "b": "2", 
    "c": "82.657170917364141", 
    "d": "foo"
  }
}
```

Loading data:

```
        d3.json('mydata.json', function(data){

            console.log(data)


        });
```

When I console.log my data I get this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rgf38dkt6nrurei/Screen%20Shot%202014-07-05%20at%2019.26.41.png

Update:

So what I would want to do is add elements for each of the .json objects but it would be nice if I could make the first number the Key.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using an associative array as data for D3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589768/using-an-associative-array-as-data-for-d3)

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: So what I would want to do is add elements for each of the .json objects but it would be nice if I could make the first number the Key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`d3.entries()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_entries) to turn your one giant object into an array containing the child objects.

When you do this, each of your array members will be an object with a `.key` property and a `.value` property. The key in your case will be `'01'` for the first member, `'02'` for the second, etc. The value will be the object with properties `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`.

For example:

```
d3.json('mydata.json', function(data) {
  console.log(d3.entries(data));
});
```

will output:

```
[{
  key: "01",
  value: {
    a: "7.9146197142424404"
    b: "8"
    c: "64.52183289033583"
    d: "bar"
  }
},
{
  key: "02",
  value: {
    a: "6.1448162722275468"
    b: "2"
    c: "82.657170917364141"
    d: "foo"
  }
}]
```

Here's an example [**PLUNK**](http://plnkr.co/edit/f9NMJYG1gUYHlr5lhxPe?p=preview)

Comment: Exactly what I needed. the data part in d3 can be a bit confusing for a beginner. I had worked with .csv files but not with .json. thanks a lot!